# Dynamics CRM Online + Node.js (request runns forever /hangs)

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm

I tried to develop a node.js module that allows the use of the SOAP web service of CRM Online: [XrmNodeKit](https://github.com/thuld/XrmNodeKit)

The code based on the JavaScript code provided by [Jason Lattimer](http://jlattimer.blogspot.de/2014/04/soap-authentication-to-crm-online-using.html)

So far I was able the retrieve the auth-token but when I execute the WhoAmI requst the web-service call just runs forever (see test "[should fetch the name of the current user](https://github.com/thuld/XrmNodeKit/blob/master/test/specification.Authentication.js#L88)", no error is thrown....

You can find the [source-code on github](https://github.com/thuld/XrmNodeKit/blob/master/lib/XrmRequest.js#L51)

Has anyone tried to consume the SOAP web-services via Node.js?

Comment: your question should probably be 'why does the request hang' and you should probably post your code that handles that request/response and any docs for the API endpoint

Comment: Hey thuld, looked at you git repo, how are you coming along with this? This is something i have thought about before, but from the C++ node plugin side of things. Would like to know if you got it working or not.

Comment: @RattyLaa - Is not working jet. But I did not found much time in the last month to proceed with this project. I am more than happy for any support.

Comment: Organization.svc and OrganizationData.svc cannot be consumed by external javascript (same-origin is enforced to prevent exploiting the platform: either it's a js web resource or the CRM flips you off). That said, it *might*, *maybe* be somehow doable On-Premise... I'd *love* for someone to find out a trick (I couldn't)

Comment: @Alex: Node.js is a server side technology, so the same rules apply as for all other technologies (Java, PHP, Python) including consuming the web services from another server. The same origin policy applies only for client side JavaScript.

Comment: @Alex this limitation still exist only in CRM 2011

Answer (score 1):

Have you found this post?http://www.alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2015/01/24/authenticating-from-a-node-js-client-to-dynamics-crm-via-ad-fs-and-oauth2/
I understand this is the correct approach. You need to use OAuth.

But it is not correct in one regard (I'm quoting an expert from the CRM product team) 
He says "*You cannot move the node.js code to client, since in this case you need to use the Implicit flow rather than the Authorization code flow , Finally after getting the OAuth token, you still cannot send it to our Web services from the client since [CRM Online] does not support CORS in 2013/2015*"

While this is a .NET sample it covers the principles, just have to make it work with Node.js: https://bitbucket.org/Georged/caseowary/overview (credits to George Doubinski)

Comment: Web archive to the rescue :)

https://web.archive.org/web/20151016042920/http://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2015/01/24/authenticating-from-a-node-js-client-to-dynamics-crm-via-ad-fs-and-oauth2/

Also, found the article - looks like it moved a day... Perhaps Alexander needs to check his timezones :) http://alexanderdevelopment.net/post/2015/01/23/authenticating-from-a-node-js-client-to-dynamics-crm-via-ad-fs-and-oauth2/